# What are Bubbling Geometries?

Tags: topology, ads-cft, branes, supergravity, bubbles

I know that Wilson loops in certain higher rank representations are dual to Bubbling Geometries. Also, certain local operators are dual to this kind of solutions. But (independently from holography), what is a bubbling geometry?
I found this paper

[Bubbling AdS space and 1/2 BPS geometries](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0409174)

and I think it is the first one using the word "bubbling". Correct me if I'm wrong.

What are the necessary characteristics of a geometry to be called bubbling geometry? I would like a definition and an explanation of why that word is used. Perhaps, are there bubbles in those solutions?

Comment: I find no reference to bubbles or bubbling in the paper except in the title.

Comment: *I know that Wilson loops in certain higher rank representations are dual to Bubbling Geometries.* How do you know this?

Comment: @Ghoster Because when you have a big enough representation, the backreaction produced by the dual D-branes configuration cannot be neglected anymore. You can read the introduction of [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0612190.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Bubbling geometries are a family of *microstate geometries*, classical nonsingular solutions in supergravity theories associated with [fuzzball paradigm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzball_%28string_theory%29).

Fuzzball program proposes that black hole information puzzle is solved by *large* corrections to classical black hole solutions starting just at the horizon, replacing the usual picture of the black hole with something else: quantum, stringy “fuzz”. A typical state of the fuzzball would, of course, be quantum, but among those states there must be some *coherent states* called *microstate geometries* that allow descriptions as solutions to classical equations of motion. Away from where horizon should be such solutions rapidly approach corresponding black hole solution but on the inside, instead of the horizon surrounding the singularity, there is a topologically nontrivial geometry being supported against the collapse by fluxes of form field.

For more details, have a look at lectures by [Warner](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.13108) or by [Mayerson](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.11394).